# Give a step by step analytic solution to the Chazy equation $f''' - 2f'f'' + f^2 = 0$, preferably using Maple to find it.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, numerical-methods, matlab, maple

The **Chazy** equation is $f''' - 2f'f'' + f^2 = 0$, I've managed to find good numerical approximations to the solution for a complex argument using Matlab, but I've heard you can find an analytic solution using methods that are beyond my understanding, but I'd still like to know how to do this so I can compare the two solutions.

Also, I'd like to then plot the solution for a complex argument using Matlab or Maple, if anyone can help with how I'd go about that.